# Core Animation - Using `makeBackingLayer` does not apply Core Image Filter

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation, ios5

I am building a CALayer backed NSView that applies a mask filter to the layer and then draws the layer.  When I build a new layer and set it on the view manually in `-(void)viewDidMoveToSuperview)` the view renders correctly, but when I override `-(CALayer *)makeBackingLayer` the filter does not get applied to the layer.

Here's the code that works (layer host view style):

```
-(void)viewDidMoveToSuperview{
  [super viewDidMoveToSuperview];
  CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithMask"];
  [filter setValue:[self transparentImage] forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];
  [filter setValue:[self maskImage] forKey:@"inputMaskImage"];

  self.layer = [TransparentLayer layer];
  self.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0, 1, 1, 1);

  [self.layer setPosition:CGPointMake(0 ,0)];
  [self.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0 ,0)];
  [self.layer setBounds:CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,200, 200)];
  self.layer.filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:filter];
  [self setWantsLayer:YES];
  [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
  [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

This renders the CALayer and the output looks like this:

[image: Layer Host]

But when I do this (Layer backed view style):

```
-(CALayer *)makeBackingLayer{

  CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithMask"];
  [filter setValue:[self transparentImage] forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];
  [filter setValue:[self maskImage] forKey:@"inputMaskImage"];

  TransparentLayer *backingLayer = [TransparentLayer layer];
  backingLayer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0, 1, 1, 1);

  [backingLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(0 ,0)];
  [backingLayer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0 ,0)];
  [backingLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,200, 200)];
  backingLayer.filters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:filter];
  return backingLayer;

}

-(void)viewDidMoveToSuperview{
  [super viewDidMoveToSuperview];
  [self setWantsLayer:YES];
}
```

The view ends up looking like this:

[image: Layer Backed View (Broken)]

Two questions:

1 - Why isn't the filter applied on the layer when using `makeBackingLayer`?

2 - How can I use `makeBackingLayer` to generate the layer rather than calling `setLayer`?

EDIT: Changing the `-(void)viewDidMoveToSuperView` to the following renders the layer like I want it to, but it still doesn't answer my question:

```
-(void)viewDidMoveToSuperview{
  [super viewDidMoveToSuperview];
  //manually set the layer
  [self setLayer:[self makeBackingLayer]];
  [self setWantsLayer:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're accessing properties of view's layer you must make the view to host layer rather than layer backed.

You cannot use `-makeBackingLayer` to customize layer of a view. Documentation mentions only one application of this method:

> In your view class, override -makeBackingLayer to return an
>   autoreleased instance of your NSOpenGLLayer subclass.

1. Because you should use `-setContentFilters:`
2. You cannot. You must call `setLayer:`

`-makeBackingLayer` is a wrong place to create your custom layer. You should add new method instead (e.g. `-makeHostLayer`).

Comment: Answer #1 (use `-setContentFilters:`) does not work for me.  (Is that an older API or iOS specific?)  But, the overall answer (use a layer hosting view as opposed to a layer backed view) is correct.
Thanks Kentzo

Comment: `-setContentFilters:` works if your view is layer backed only.

Comment: I think this is not 100% correct, in general sure you can use `makeBackingLayer` to create your own backing layer and this is documented in the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide) in section [Setting Up Layer Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH13-SW12). You have to call for this `setWantsLayer:`. The rest is correct, backing layer is not layer hosting.

Comment: Came across my very own answer while revisiting some very old code I wrote. Still, as of 10.15 overriding -makeBackingLayer: to return _custom_ layer does something to the view that AppKit keeps its hands off it.